# How to apply approximation of probability?

Tags: probability

I am working on a question in "Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition, by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsilis":

A factory produces $X_{n}$ gadgets on day n. where the $X_{n}$ are independant and identically distributed random variables, with mean 4 and variance 9.

The question that I have is:

Find an approximation to the probability that the total number of gadgets produced in 100 days in less than 440.

The solution starts with

$$ P(S_{100}<440)=P(S_{100}\leq 439.5) =....$$

Would anyone please tell me where this 439.5 is obtained?

Comment: The number produced is an integer.  If it is $<440$ then it is at most $439$ so certainly $\leq439.5$.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: This is [continuity correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction).